# Running initializing function in namespace at the beginning of Program

Tags: c++

I've researched a bit on the topic but it's becoming difficult since the search results tend to think I mean constructors for objects.

I'm wanting to wrap a lib in a structure I can later use freely with different assumptions baked in. The lib has an init function meant to be run before any further functions and a terminate function to release the resources and clean everything.

I'm wanting to make sure that these functions are always going to run even if I forget to add them later on. I think it would clear up the code a fair bit and allow the resulting main to just focus on the task it performs.

The closest thing that works that I have been able to find is creating a struct/class within the namespace, give it a constructor and deconstructor and instantiate it withing the namespace. From the test I've run it seems to work as intended. This is example code:

```
#define lib_uninit -100
#define lib_init 0

namespace myLib{
int lib_state = lib_uninit;

int init(){
    if(lib_state == lib_init){
        myLog(logNotice, "myLib: lib already initialized. Continuing.");
        return lib_state;
    }

    lib_state = libInitialise();
    
    if(lib_state != lib_init){
        myLog<__LINE__>(logError, "myLib: Failed to initialized lib.");
    }

    return lib_state;
}

int uninit(){
    libTerminate();
}

struct initHelper{

    initHelper(){
        init();
    }
    ~initHelper(){
        uninit();
    }
};

initHelper myHelper;
}
```

It truly feels that this approach is nonsensical and dirty even if it works. I'm feeling that this is a common want so I'm hoping there isn't a built in/ intended way of doing just what I'm looking for.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Instead of using those free functions and global variables, you can wrap all of them in the class. Creating that class instance will call the constructor and at the end destructor will be called.

Comment: I'm not sureif I'm not misunderstanding you, that is what I did within the namespace? I do want it to be run on it's own without having to call it in the main function. Just using this lib will automatically call the init function is the intention.

I do want them to be free floating in the namespace in the case that I want to call one or the other at different points within the program. A bit more flexibility and within the namespace to identify them as being part of that usecase

Comment: Making sure that globals are initialised before they are used is a common C++ problem. There's no built in support for this (unless C++20 modules add something, I wouldn't know about that). Two common techniques are Meyer singletons and [nifty counters](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Nifty_Counter). I'm afraid I don't understand your code, you never use the `initHelper` class and what do namespaces have to do with this issue?

Comment: You should avoid global variables alltogether (specially with libs). Create an abstract base with getter functions for the data you need, derive a struct/class from it. Create an instance of it in main and pass it on to the code that needs that data. This is the dependency injection pattern. Learn about it and your future you will thank you (specialy when writing unit testable code)

Comment: If you forget to initialize something you should throw an exception and print an error message.

Comment: @john the idea behind the initHelper is just to have the object instantiated so it'll execute it's constructor before starting the main function and deconstructor at the end of the program.

Comment: I've kind of settled on ignoring this approach in favor of using signal handling to make sure the uninit function gets run on abort of program. I sat down and narrowed my goals a bit and this is the one I truly need to make sure is handled. if you forget to init and uninit in the main I'll just send you to the wolfs and not care. Sig handling for the Ctr + C situation that would leave a running state on the resources